# Html button action only on first click

Tags: php, html, button, onclick, action

I can set action on click for html button. But I need to set action only on FIRST click. Is there any way to do this? The button is radio in form. Some javascript maybe?

What's important - the radio button still might be changed. But action has to be done only once.

This doesn't work

```
function myfunction(i){
oForm = document.forms["myform"];
if(oForm.elements["field"+i].checked)
    alert("action done earlier");
else
    action
}
```

Comment: You could use a boolean, or removeEventListener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleanest solution is probably to use [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/element.removeEventListener) to... remove the event listener :

```
var myButton = document.getElementById('someId');
var handler = function(){
   // doSomething
   myButton.removeEventListener('click',handler);
}
myButton.addEventListener('click', handler);
```

(to make it cleaner, you could wrap this in an IIFE, as in the example below)

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ayufat/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the jQuery [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) event handler.

```
$("#my-button").one('click', function() {
    /* Do something at most once */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you preffer jQuery, You can use jQuery unbind

```
$("button").click(function(){
  /* some content */
  $(this).unbind('click');
});
```

Html

```
<button> Some content </button>
```

Comment: There's no jQuery in this question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a property to disable the button once it has been clicked, adding

```
disabled="disabled"
```

to the button once clicked ?

Comment: But i want to change the value. So button can't be disabled. Only action has to be done once.

Comment: OK so I guess the Javascript answers will suit you better

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this problem I have used jQuery.on as well as jQuery.off - see my code on jsfiddle!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var button = $('#my-button');

    function onClick() {
        alert('clicked');
        button.off('click', onClick);
    };

    button.on('click', onClick);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VxRyn/

Comment: This requires jQuery, which OP didn't mention.